# Pascal - ошибка. Нет перегруженной подпрограммы

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

```
Type 
   data=record
   okrug:integer;
   fio: string[40];
   name: string[20]; 
   age:integer;
   prof: string[20];
end;

var
 sp, st:string;
 party: array[1..100] of string;
 i,j,n:integer;
 kondidat:array[1..100] of data;
 tin, tout:file of data;
 ttask:text;

procedure inputOfFile();
begin
 Assign(tin,'input.dat');
 Reset(tin);
 i:=1;
 while Eof(tin)=false do
  begin
    Read(tin, kondidat[i]);
    Writeln(kondidat[i].okrug, ' ', kondidat[i].fio,  ' ', kondidat[i].name, ' ', kondidat[i].age, ' ', kondidat[i].prof);
    inc(i);
  end;
 n:=i-1;
 close(tin);
end;

procedure outputFile();
 var i:integer;
begin
 Assign(tout,'input.dat');
 Reset(tout);
 for i:=1 to n do
  begin
    Write(tout, kondidat[i]);
  end;
 close(tout);
end;

procedure sAge();
 var 
  s:array [1..100] of string;
  age:array [1..100, 1..2] of real;
  i,j,k:integer;
  sp:string;
  f:boolean;
begin
 Assign(ttask,'age.txt');
 Rewrite(ttask);
 k:=0;
 for i:=1 to n do
  begin
   f:=false;
   for j:=1 to k do
    if (kondidat[i].name = s[j]) then
     begin
      age[j,1]:=age[j,1]+kondidat[i].age;
      age[j,2]:=age[j,2]+1;
      f:=true;
     end;
   if (f=false) then
    begin
     k:=k+1;
     s[k]:=kondidat[i].name;
     age[k,1]:=kondidat[i].age;
     age[k,2]:=1;
    end;  
  end; 
 for i:=1 to k do
  begin
   sp:='Партия: ' + s[i] + ' Средний возраст: ' + age[i,1]/age[i,2];
   writeln(sp);
   write(ttask,sp);
  end;
 Close(ttask);
end;

procedure sProf();
 var 
  s:array [1..100,1..2] of string;
  sp:array [1..100] of string;
  count:array [1..100] of integer;
  st:string;
  i,j,k,l,p, num:integer;
  f:boolean;
begin
 Assign(ttask,'prof.txt');
 Rewrite(ttask);
 k:=0;
 for i:=1 to n do
  begin
   f:=false;
   for j:=1 to k do
    if (kondidat[i].name = s[j,1]) then
      f:=true;
   if (f=false) then
    begin
     k:=k+1;
     s[k,1]:=kondidat[i].name;
    end;  
  end; 
 for j:=1 to k do
  begin
   l:=0;
   for i:=1 to n do
    if (kondidat[i].name = s[j,1]) then  
     begin
      f:=false;
      for p:=1 to l do
       if sp[p]=kondidat[i].prof then
         begin count[p]:=count[p]+1; f:=true; end;
      if f=false then
       begin
        l:=l+1;
        count[l]:=1;
        sp[l]:=kondidat[i].prof;
       end;
     end;
   p:=count[1];
   num:=1;
   for i:=1 to l do
    if count[i]>p then
     begin
      p:=count[i];
      num:=i;     
     end;
   s[j,2]:=sp[num];
  end;

 for i:=1 to k do
  begin
   st:='Партия: ' + s[i,1] + ' Наиболее встречающаяся профессия: ' + s[i,2];
   writeln(st);
   write(ttask,st);
  end;
 Close(ttask);
end;


procedure addKondidat();
 var i:integer;
begin
 inc(n);
 write('Введите Ф_И_О: ');
 readln(kondidat[n].fio);
 write('Введите номер округа: ');
 readln(kondidat[n].okrug);
 write('Введите наименование партии: ');
 readln(kondidat[n].name);
 write('Введите возраст: ');
 readln(kondidat[n].age);
 write('Введите профессию: ');
 readln(kondidat[n].prof); 
end;

procedure menu();
begin
 writeln('Выберите действие:');
 writeln(' 1. Прочитать из файла данные');
 writeln(' 2. Перезаписать данные в файл');
 writeln(' 3. Добавить кондидата');
 writeln(' 4. Вычислить средний возраст кондидатов от партии');
 writeln(' 5. Вычислить наиболее частую профессию кондидатов от партии');
 writeln(' 0. Выход');
end;

begin
 i:=1;
 while i<>0 do
  begin
   menu();
   readln(i);   
   case i of
    1 : inputOfFile();
    2 : outputFile();
    3 : addKondidat();
    4 : sAge();
    5 : sProf();
   end;
  end;
end.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну так вы начали складывать строки с числами...

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в том, что вы складываете строки с числом. Используйте функцию преобразования числа в строку, в данном случае - `FloatToStr`:

```
sp := 'Партия: ' + s[i] + ' Средний возраст: ' + FloatToStr(age[i, 1] / age[i, 2]);
```